# How to freeze sprite animation on last frame?

Tags: game-maker, gml

I want to make a sprite in game maker that contains 5 sub images to stop when it reaches the last one how can I do this using code?

Answer (score 8):

In `Animation End` event:

```
image_speed = 0;
image_index = image_number - 1;
```

Comment: When I use this code, the animation doesn't even start

Comment: This code stops animation after animation played once. See [example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78963719/stackoverflow/gml/animation_one_time.gmz)

Comment: You have to put it in the Animation End event...I'm assuming you put it in step

Answer (score 1):

Run this in the Step even of your object:

```
If image_index == 4 Then image_speed = 0;
```

`image_index` is the index of the current frame in the object's sprite's animation, `image_speed` is the speed of the animation (in frames per step).    This code just checks if the animation is at the final frame (the frames are 0-indexed, so the 5th frame is index 4.), and if so sets the speed to `0`.

Comment: it gives me this error: 

Unable to find any instance for object index '12' name 'obj_arrow_move_one_direction'
 at gml_Object_obj_magnet_StepNormalEvent_3 (line 13) - if(obj_arrow_move_one_direction.image_index==4)