# Sprite in Game Maker doesn't act the way I want it to

Tags: gml

I'm currently working on animating my player so that he behaves like he's breathing.

```
if(time mod 60==0){
   if(image_index==0){
     image_index=1;
   }
   else{
     image_index=0;
   }
}
time++;
```

The whole thing is put in the step event and sprite is changing every single step and it even changes to an index 2 and 3, which I haven't even used in the code.

So if anyone has some ideas why does it work like this then please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the sprite you use has multiple sub-images. GameMaker will naturally iterate the image index every frame.
So first, you need to stop the animation from running with

```
image_speed = 0;
```

You have to run this line when the sprite has just been changed, so ideally just after the "sprite_index" variable is changed. If you don't change it, just set image_speed to zero in the creation code.

If you are curious, I found the answer here : [How to freeze sprite animation on last frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576900/how-to-freeze-sprite-animation-on-last-frame)